# Display fields depending on output checkbox - laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, checkbox, show-hide

My form contains multiple fields. One of the fields is a selection. If in the select box yes is selected, two extra fields should appear. But for some reason, it isn't working.
I am using jquery to let the fields appear. Bellow, you can find my code. Thanks for the help.

## Start blade template

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
<div class="container col-sm-12">
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayFields() {
    if (document.getElementById("isYes").selected) {
        document.getElementById("ifyes").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("ifno").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ifno").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("ifyes").style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>


        <style>
        .hide{
        display:none;
        }
        .show {
        display: block;
        }
        </style>
```

After the jquery, I added directly the form where I am trying to hide or show the fields.

```
<form action="/events" method="POST">
@csrf

            ...
                    <div class="d-flex">                    
                        <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                        <select name="condition" class="form-control" onchange="displayFields()" required>
                                <option>{{old('condition')}}</option>
                                <option id="isYes">Yes</option>
                                <option id="isNo">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div> 
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="p-1">
                            <label class="p-2" for="type" id="ifyes" style="display: none;">Type</label>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-4"> 
                    <div class="d-flex">                       
                        <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                            <input  id="ifyes" style="display: none;"
                                    type="text" 
                                    class="form-control input-text" 
                                    placeholder="Type"
                                    name="type" 
                                    value="{{old('type')}}"
                            >
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="p-1">
                            <label class="p-2" for="function" id="ifyes" style="display: none;">function</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4"> 
                    <div class="d-flex">   
                        <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                            <input  id="ifyes" style="display: none;"
                                    type="text" 
                                    class="form-control input-text" 
                                    placeholder="function"
                                    name="function" 
                                    value="{{old('function')}}"
                            >
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

## layout.blade.php

```
<head>
<title>@yield('title',"Event Planner")</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="base-url" content="{{ url('/') }}">

<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Comment: You are using multiple of the same id in your HTML tags (`id="ifyes"`). You should be using classes there instead.

Comment: I had a similar question. Maybe this could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524251/displaying-or-hiding-multiple-fields-based-on-selection-dropdown-jquery

Comment: @Nemo thanks it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where I ended up with thanks to the input of @ageans and @Mohamed.

```
 function showType(i){

        var x = document.getElementById("showType"+i);
        var y = document.getElementById("showTypeLabel"+i);
        var z = document.getElementById("selectType"+i);

        if (z.options[z.selectedIndex].value == "Yes"){
            x.style.display = "block";
            y.style.display = "block";
        }else{
            x.style.display = "none";
            y.style.display = "none";
        }        
    }
```

```
<select name="condition" class="form-control" onchange="showType(0)" required>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>

<input  id="showTypeLabel0" style="display: none;" type="text"  class="form-control input-text" 
         placeholder="Type" name="type"  value="{{old('type')}}"
>
 <input  id="showType0" style="display: none;"
          type="text" 
          class="form-control input-text" 
          placeholder="function"
          name="function" 
          value="{{old('function')}}"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate Id's in your html. Id's should be unique. Classes can have the same class on multiple elements. But Id's should be unique to each element. And If you are using JQuery, you could use this to handle change. Using `.change()` and chaining with `.addClass()` & `.removeClass()` method. With the provided information, here is an example that may help. This is the same thing and does the same thing but more "JQuery":

```
<style>
  .hide{
  display:none;
}
  .show {
  display: block;
}
</style>


//Add an ID and remove the onChange
//Add value instead of ID to the options
<select name="condition" class="form-control" id="select-condition" required>
   <option>{{old('condition')}}</option>
   <option value="yes">Yes</option>
   <option value="no">No</option>
</select>

<label class="hide p-2" for="function" id="label1">function One</label>
<label class="hide p-2" for="function" id="label2">function Two</label>

//We are going to listen for any changes of the select field
$( "#select-condition" ).change(function() {
  if(this.value == 'yes'){
    $('#label1').removeClass( "hide" );
    $('#label2').addClass( "hide" );
  }else if(this.value == 'no'){
    $('#label1').addClass( "hide" );
    $('#label2').removeClass( "hide" );
  }
  else{
    $('#label1').removeClass( "show" ).addClass("hide");
    $('#label2').removeClass( "show" ).addClass("hide");
  }
});
```

Here is the working link to **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5o91enzq/)**

**Note:** Don't forget to add the JQuery to your project and the JQuery should be linked before the code. Code should be below

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Can you show me where you added the jquery? And where you code is? Can you please update your answer? Paste the blade file

Comment: Where is your JQuery link? Did you link your JQuery? Paste this above my script: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and put the style above the code.

Comment: Also, is the form coming after the script? Please remove the `type="text/javascript"` from script tag for now. And copy paste my above comment script above the script tag

Comment: The form is coming after the script. I just removed all my code and paste your code in my blade template and added the link. Even your code is not working.

Comment: What does you console error say? When you right click on browser empty area and select 'inspect element' and go to 'console' tab and see what error you are getting there

Comment: Are you able to upload your Laravel project (the whole project) to git or something?

Comment: Not the whole project. But is there a file you need to have to find the problem.

Comment: It would be better to have the whole project. You can remove all sensitive stuff and upload the project. A file won’t let me know what the issue is. I will have to dig in to see the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197921/discussion-between-ageans-and-mohamed-ahmed).