# Displaying or hiding multiple fields based on selection dropdown - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, dropdown, show-hide

I have a form containing a dropdown. Depending on the selection made in the dropdown, multiple fields should appear or hide.
The jquery function, I have written, works only for one fields. If I select no in the dropdown only the title what is hidden the rest stays. 
I don't quite understand why.
I could solve this by giving each field id another name (for example showing1, showing2, ...) and refer to this id in the function but that is a lot of repetition.

Shouldn't there be a better way?

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/g0x7dc4y/) to fiddle.

Thanks for the input.

```
## jQuery

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showing').hide();
    $('#condition').change(
        function(){
            if(this.value == "yes"){
                $('#showing').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#showing').hide();
            }
        }
    )
});

### Part of the form
    <div class="col-4"> 
                    <div class="d-flex">                    
                        <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                        <select name="playing" class="form-control" id="condition" required>
                                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                                <option value="no">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="p-1">
                            <label class="p-2" for="what" id="showing" >What</label>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-4"> 
                    <div class="d-flex">                       
                        <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                            <input  id="showing"
                                    type="text" 
                                    class="form-control input-text" 
                                    name="wat" 
                            >
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="p-1">
                        <label class="p-2" for="type" id="showing" >Type</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4"> 
                    <div class="d-flex">
```

Comment: You should use class, not id.

Comment: Remove id `showing` from your elements and move them all in a container div with the id `showing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you should remove id "showing" from elements and add a class name "showing" or you can add this class to the parent element of all these elements. second, you should change your id to class in jquery. and I think you didn't add the script that loads jquery.

code after edit:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.showing').hide();
        $('#condition').change(
            function(){
                if(this.value == "yes"){
                    $('.showing').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('.showing').hide();
                }
            }
        )
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-4"> 
                        <div class="d-flex">                    
                            <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                            <select name="playing" class="form-control" id="condition" required>
                                    <option value="no">No</option>
                                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                
 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <div class="p-1">
                                <label class="p-2 showing" for="what">What</label>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-4"> 
                        <div class="d-flex">                       
                            <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                                <input
                                        type="text" 
                                        class="form-control input-text showing" 
                                        name="wat" 
                                >
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <div class="p-1">
                            <label class="p-2 showing" for="type">Type</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4"> 
                        <div class="d-flex">   
                            <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                                <input
                                        type="text" 
                                        class="form-control input-text showing" 
                                        name="type" 
                                >
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>     
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please check HTML rules for define input id and class **

> Element IDs should be unique within the entire document.

```
       <div>
      <img src="https://playcode.io/static/img/logo.png" 
        alt="PlayCode logo">
        <h1 id="msg"></h1>
       <div class="col-4"> 
                    <div class="d-flex">                    
                        <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                        <select name="playing" class="form-control" id="condition" required>
                                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                                <option value="no">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div> 

   <div class="row">
               <div class="what_hide">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="p-1">
                            <label class="p-2" for="what" id="showing" >What</label>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-4"> 
                    <div class="d-flex">                       
                        <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                            <input  id="wat"
                                    type="text" 
                                    class="form-control input-text" 
                                    name="wat" 
                            >
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="p-1">
                        <label class="p-2" for="type"  >Type</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4"> 
                    <div class="d-flex">   
                        <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                            <input  id="new"
                                    type="text" 
                                    class="form-control input-text" 
                                    name="type" 
                            >
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>     
            </div>
```

> JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.what_hide').hide();
    $('#condition').change(
        function(){
            if(this.value == "yes"){
                $('.what_hide').show();
            }
            else {
                $('.what_hide').hide();
            }
        }
    )
});
```